# Is there any difference between "standard" and block package declaration?

Tags: perl

Usually, a package starts simply as

```
package Cat;
... #content
!0;
```

I just discovered that starting from the perl 5.14 there is the "block" syntax too.

```
package Cat {
    ... #content
}
```

It is probably the same. But just to be sure, is there **any** difference?

And about the `1;` at the end of the package file. The return value of any block, is taken as the value of the last evaluated expression. So can I put the `1;` before the closing `}`? To make `require` happy, is there any difference between:

```
package Cat {
    ... #content
    1; 
}
```

and

```
package Cat {
    ... #content 
}
1;
```

Comment: I'm just suggesting that if `require` is happy either way (no difference), then there is no difference with respect to `require`. Do you mean to say that finding answers by trying the code yourself is not helpful at all?

Comment: @Nemo `package NAME {...}` is just syntactic sugar for `{package NAME; ...}`; they are the exactly same thing. If the last statement in your file is a block, then the last statement in the block is the value `require` will get.

Comment: To be fair, your question didn't mention that you tried it yourself and found no difference, so I was suggesting that maybe you could try it (for the 2nd part). Since you found it to be offensive (even though it was not my intention), I shall remove the offending comment.

Comment: Why use `!0;` rather that just `1;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course there is a difference. The second variant has a *block*.

A `package` declaration sets the current namespace for subs and globals. This is scoped normally, i.e. the scope ends with the end of file or eval string, or with an enclosing block.

The `package NAME BLOCK` syntax is just *syntactic sugar* for

```
{ package NAME;
  ...;
}
```

and even compiles down to the *same* opcodes.

While the `package` declaration is syntactically a statement, this isn't semantically true; it just sets compile-time properties. Therefore, the last statement of the last block is the last statement of the file, and there is no difference between

```
package Foo;
1;
```

and

```
package Foo {
  1;
}
```

wrt. the last statement.

The `package BLOCK` syntax is interesting mainly because it looks like `class Foo {}` in other languages, I think. Because the block limits scope, this also makes using properly scoped variables easier. Think:

```
package Foo;
our $x = 1;
package main;
$::x = 42;
say $x;
```

Output: `1`, because `our` is lexically scoped like `my` and just declares an alias! This can be prevented by the block syntax:

```
package Foo {
  our $x = 1;
}
package main {
  $::x = 42;
  say $x;
}
```

works as expected (`42`), although `strict` isn't happy.

Answer (score 5):

```
package Foo { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
{ package Foo; ... }
```

which is different from the following in that it create a block

```
package Foo; ...
```

This only matters if you have code that follows in the file.

---

```
package Foo { ... }
```

**isn't** equivalent to

```
BEGIN { package Foo; ... }
```

I would have liked this, but that proposal was not accepted.

---

`require` (and `do`) requires that the last expression evaluated in the file returns a true value. `{ ... }` evaluates to the last value evaluated within, so the following is fine:

```
package Foo { ...; 1 }
```

Placing the `1;` on the outside makes more sense to me — it pertains to the file rather than the package — but that's merely a style choice.

Answer (score 3):

**There is** a difference :) If you can try running below two different code snippets (just import the modules in a perl file )

```
# perlscript.pl

use wblock;

wblock::wbmethod();
```

First Code snippet without block, **wblock.pm**

```
package wblock1;
my $a =10;
sub wbmethod1{
        print "in wb $a";
}

package wblock;

sub wbmethod{
        print "in wb1 $a";
}
1;
```

Second with **wblock.pm**

```
package wblock1 {
my $a =10;
sub wbmethod1{
        print "in wb $a";
}
1;
}

package wblock {
sub wbmethod{
        print "in wb1 $a";
}
1;
}
```

Now the difference as you might have seen is, variable `$a` is not available for `wblock` package when we use BLOCK. But without BLOCK we can use `$a` from other package, as it's scope is for file.

More to say from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) itself:

> That is, the forms without a BLOCK are operative through the end of
>   the current scope, just like the my, state, and our operators.

Comment: What do you mean by "You cannot use 1; separately for each package, if you have multiple packages without BLOCK. You will get error for that."? Can you post a code sample which causes the error? I tried it and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: The `1;` is added to the end of a `*.pm` file to indicate to the Perl compiler that the file was loaded correctly. It has nothing to do with packages. Because of this, there should be only one `1;` and it should be at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference but only if you are doing hard-to-maintain programming. Specially, if you are using a `my` variable across packages. The convention for Perl is to have only one package per file and the entire package in one file.

Answer (score 1):

There's one other difference that other answers haven't given, that may help explain why there are two.

```
package Foo;
sub bar { ... }
```

was always the way to do it in Perl 5. The `package BLOCK` syntax of

```
package Foo {
  sub bar { ... }
}
```

was only added at perl 5.14.

The main difference then is that the latter form is neater but only works since 5.14; the former form will work back to older versions. The neater form was added largely for visual neatness; it doesn't have any semantic difference worth worrying about.