# Access "external" Perl Array from "BEGIN" Block/Package

Tags: perl

Below is a simplified version of a perl script I am trying to modify:

```
use MODULE_1 ;
use MODULE_2 ;
use vars qw(%ARR  $VarZZ) ;

sub A {
    # Somestuff

    # Call to Sub B
    B() ;
    # Call to Sub C
    C() ;
}

BEGIN {
    package XYZ ;
    use vars qw($VarYY  $VarXX) ;
    # MISC SUBS HERE
    # end of package XYZ
}

sub B {
    # Somestuff
}

sub C {
    # Somestuff to set %ARR
}

# Call to Sub A
A() ;
```

My issue is that I will like to access %ARR within the package XYZ BEGIN block but keep getting error messages saying I need to define %ARR ("requires explicit package name")

I have tried, trying to copy a similar example within the block, `$main::ARR{index}` but failed so far.

I assume it may be because %ARR isn't set when that block is begin evaluated and that I need to call "sub C" perhaps but `&main::C();` seems to be failing as well.

How can I access this array there?

I have looked at: [Perl's main package - block syntax - pragmas and BEGIN/END blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988642/perls-main-package-block-syntax-pragmas-and-begin-end-blocks) which seems to be addressing similar themes but struggling to properly understand the answers

## ** EDIT **

Expanded skeleton script showing some attempts at moving forward:

```
use MODULE_1 ;
use MODULE_2 ;
use vars qw(%ARR  $VarZZ) ;

sub A {
    # Somestuff

    # Call to Sub B
    B() ;
    # Call to Sub C
    C() ;
    # Call to Sub E
    E() ;
}

sub E {
    # Call to Package XYZ subs
}

BEGIN {
    package XYZ ;
    use vars qw($VarYY  $VarXX %ARR) ;

    # I tried to Call to Sub C and load a local version of %ARR
    #
    # This fails with "Undefined subroutine &main::C" error
    &main::C() ;
    #
    # We never get here so not sure if correct
    %ARR = &main::ARR ;


    # MISC SUBS HERE
        sub X {
            # Call to Sub D
            &main::D() ;
        }
    # end of package XYZ
}

sub B {
    # Somestuff
}

sub C {
    # Somestuff to set %ARR
}
sub D {
    # Somestuff
}

# Call to Sub A
A() ;
```

Note the the call to `&main::E()` works when called within the Subs in Package XYZ but both this and `&main::C()` fail when running free standing. Perhaps the free standing call is done at complile time before the subs are defined.

BTW, I tried the `our` definition but getting a 502 error: [Nginx Debug Log](http://pastebin.com/qt2GT7ZP)

Perhaps this is because the array is not available?

Comment: Have you also looked at `my`, `our`, `local` and `state`. I think its related to scoping mechanisms of perl since your problem seems to be rooted there.

Comment: just using `$main::ARR{...}` / `%main::ARR` will get the right variable (as would declaring `our %ARR;` as @mob suggests), but only you would be able to tell if the subs in XYZ:: end up getting called before C() is called and the variable is set as you expect.

Comment: It is recommended (in the documentation) that you do not use `use vars` above Perl version 5.6. Use `our`, or preferably `my` instead.

Comment: you say `&main::C()` is failing?  how?

Comment: @ysth I get a 500 Internal Server Error with a `Undefined subroutine &main::C called at /path/to/file.pl line 123` error message in my log.

Comment: well, yes, BEGIN interrupts the compilation and runs the code in it before resuming; when the BEGIN block is running, `sub C ...` hasn't even been compiled yet.

Comment: So moving the BEGIN to the end of the file should help but still getting the "undefined" error. Perhaps I am missing something although the skeleton I gave appears correct. I will recheck )over 20k lines of code!). I think I will just try to replicate Sub C in Package XYZ although that is really a last resort and still hoping for a better integrated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%main:ARR` or `$main::ARR{index}` are correct for the code skeleton you have provided (well, anything is correct because you haven't said `use strict`, but anyway ...). Is it possible that `main` is not the correct namespace (i.e., is there some `pacakge` statement that precedes `use vars ...`) ?

In any case, you can workaround this issue with the `our` keyword. If you declare it at the top level, it will have scope throughout the rest of the file:

```
package ABC;
our %ARR;      # %ABC::ARR

sub foo {
   $ARR{"key"} = "value";  # %ABC::ARR
}

{   # "BEGIN" optional
    package XYZ;
    our %Hash;    # %XYZ::Hash
    sub bar {
        my $key1 = $Hash{"key1"};  # %XYZ::Hash
        my $val1 = $ARR{$key1};    # %ABC::ARR
        $ARR{$val1} = $key1;
    }
}

...
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. The 502 errors I was getting were due to other issues. Thanks!